# No Valid keystore with jetty on spring-boot

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, jetty, keystore

I have a spring boot project that is running jetty and I am trying to register ssl using

```
@Bean(name = "containerCustomizer")
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer()
{
    return (container -> ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container).addServerCustomizers(
            new JettyServerCustomizer()
            {
                @Override
                public void customize(Server server)
                {
                    // HTTP
                    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
                    connector.setPort(80);

                    // HTTPS
                    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(
                            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystore.jks").getFile());
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

                    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
                    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

                    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                                                                       new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,
                                                                                                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1
                                                                                                        .asString()),
                                                                       new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
                    sslConnector.setPort(443);
                    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connector, sslConnector});
                }
            }));
}
```

When I run

```
jar tf my_jar.jar | grep keystore
```

I see it saying.

`keystore.jks`

When I try to print this value

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystore.jks").getFile()
```

I get

```
file:/root/project/my_jar.jar!/keystore.jks
```

However if I run

```
new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystore.jks").getFile()).exists()
```

It always returns false.

How do I point to keystore.jks that is located inside my jar file? It is clearly there, but no matter what I try to point to it, nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `jar:file://<filesystem-path>!/<jar-path>` is a URL, not a File from the point of view of Java.

Do this ...

```java
URL urlKeystore = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystore.jks")
sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(Resource.newResource(urlKeystore));
```

Referencing:

- apidoc for [org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(Resource)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#setKeyStoreResource-org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource-)
- apidoc for [org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource.newResource(URL)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/resource/Resource.html#newResource-java.net.URL-)

Comment: I am so thankful to you man!!!I lost two day's worth of sleep, and now thanks to you I can get back to sleep. Thank you!!! I am really grateful for your answer!